Ubuntu OS: How can I recover deleted files?
I deleted 2-3 folder and files with Shift+Delete.
How I can recover the files? Please give steps and software.

FYI:  You've provided few specifics; we don't know what Ubuntu product/release you're using, what app you used to perform the delete, nor what file-system is involved. On my box here (maybe different desktop/release to yours) on some file-managers it's simply going to trash & clicking restore, but at other locations there is no such feature (as some of my file-systems have no trash) & its more involved (some of my files are on foreign file-systems I access thru network shares too). I'd use different procedures based on many details including where/what was deleted & how.
